# How to delete selected SQL Entries with a VBA Checkbox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, checkbox, sql-delete

i'm working on a web tool , which enters dates into a SQL table.
It works but it needs improvent and i dont use VB often.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

What i want is that the tool deletes ,with a Click-Button" every SQL entry (GridView) from my table , where i put the check  on the checkbox

How do i code that in VB.Net?

EDIT : Im using Microsoft Visual Studio with ASP/VB.Net

**EDIT: Design Code**

```
<div class="style1">
   &nbsp;
     <b> Datum:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <BDP:BasicDatePicker ID="datum" runat="server" DateFormat="d" />
    </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <b>Bezeichnung:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBezeich" runat="server" Height="18px" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
    </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <b>Faktor :
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfaktor" runat="server" Height="18px" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
    </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <b>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Height="22px" 
        style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; background-color: #006666" Text="Add" 
        Width="62px" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Height="22px" 
        style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; background-color: #006666" 
        Text="Delete" Width="62px" />

    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="cmdUpdate" runat="server" Height="22px" 
        style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; background-color: #006666" 
        Text="Update" Width="62px" />
    &nbsp;
    </b>
    <b><br /> Definitionen für Faktor:
  <br />  0: Ganzer Feiertag
  <br /> 0,5 : halber Feiertag
  <br /> 0,33 : ein-Drittel Feiertag
  <br /> usw.
    <br /></b>

</div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#F3F3F3" 
    CaptionAlign="Right" DataSourceID="dsFeiertag" Height="133px" PageSize="25" 
    style="text-align: left; font-family: Calibri; font-size: small; margin-bottom: 0px;" 
    Width="477px" >
    <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_hid1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Datum" HeaderText="Datum" SortExpression="Datum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Bezeichnung" HeaderText="Bezeichnung" SortExpression="Bezeichnung" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Faktor" HeaderText="Faktor" SortExpression="Faktor" />

    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#2E0A31" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**EDIT:  Functions code**

```
Partial Public Class FeiertagsTool

Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim adoBIWEB_BIUSERLogin As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim adoDWH As New ADODB.Connection

Dim cred As ReportServerCredentials
Dim Dstr As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'If UserName = "" Or Pwd = "" Then
    '    Server.Transfer("~/Mainpage.aspx", True)
    '    Exit Sub
    'End If
    GetHit(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, Request.UserHostAddress)
    adoDWH.ConnectionString = "DSN=Report_DWH_Stage;User ID=BI_WEB_USER;Password=xs4dwh;"
    adoDWH.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseServer

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
    adoDWH.Open()

    If txtfaktor.Text <> "" Then

        adoDWH.Execute("update External_Inputs.VOXPARK.Feiertag set Faktor = " & Replace(txtfaktor.Text, ",", ".") & " where Datum =  convert(date,'" & datum.Text & "',104)")
    End If
    If txtBezeich.Text <> "" Then
        adoDWH.Execute("update External_Inputs.VOXPARK.Feiertag set Bezeichnung = '" & txtBezeich.Text & "' where Datum =  convert(date,'" & datum.Text & "',104)")
    End If
    GridView1.DataBind()
    adoDWH.Close()
End Sub

Protected Sub cmdDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click
    adoDWH.Open()
    adoDWH.Execute("delete from External_Inputs.VOXPARK.Feiertag where Datum =  convert(date,'" & datum.Text & "',104)")
    GridView1.DataBind()
    adoDWH.Close()
End Sub


Protected Sub cmdAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click
    adoDWH.Open()
    adoDWH.Execute("insert into  External_Inputs.VOXPARK.Feiertag ([Datum],[Bezeichnung],[Faktor]) values( convert(date,'" & datum.Text & "',104) , '" & txtBezeich.Text & "' ," & Replace(txtfaktor.Text, ",", ".") & ")")
    GridView1.DataBind()
    adoDWH.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnnFg.png`enter code here`

Comment: Why do you want VBA for a Web Application?  Show us the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: ok codes are added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in getting back to this.  It was too hot yesterday, so I headed to the pool.

In your delete command you need to loop through the contents of the GridView to find the rows that are checked.  Once you have the row you can easily get the text of the holiday that needs deleting.  You need to loop through the GridView itself (rather than the underlying data, which is more common), because the Checkbox is unbound.

To loop through the GridView, use something like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim test As CheckBox
        test = CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(1), CheckBox)
        If test.Checked = True Then
            MsgBox(row.Cells(1).Text + " must be deleted")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Obviously where I have a message box, you need to build instead a sql command string to delete the date matching row.Cells(1).Text.  You should have enough now to fix the rest yourself.  Please feel free to get back to me, if you need further help.

Comment: help me  a lot and it worked after a  couple of tries . thank you very much

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Please mark the question as answered.@RobertD.M